# Elimino un registro con Ajax pero no muestra que lo hace,sigue apareciendo en el front-end

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código que su función es eliminar registros, y lo hace. Pero el registro sigue mostrándose hasta que manualmente actualizo la página, no lo hace ajax. El error que me muestra es el siguiente: ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2016-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2016" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2016" aria-selected="true">2016</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2017-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2017" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2017" aria-selected="false">2017</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2018-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2018" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2018" aria-selected="false">2018</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2019-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2019" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2019" aria-selected="false">2019</a>
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-2020-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2020" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2020" aria-selected="false">2020</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-content col-lg-10" id="v-pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2016" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2016-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2017" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2017-tab">

              <div id="main">
                @foreach($photos as $photo)
                  @if($photo->year == '2017')
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="pic">
                      <div class="item{{$photo->id}}">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset($photo->dir . $photo->filename . '.' .$photo->extension) }}" alt="">
                        <button class="delete-button delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$photo->id}}" data-title="{{$photo->title}}">
                          <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2018" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2018-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2019" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2019-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active pl-5" id="v-pills-2020" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2020-tab">



            </div>

          </div>
        </div>           
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Modal form to delete a form -->
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h5 class="text-center">Confirme que quiere eliminar la fotografía</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-dismiss="modal">
        Sí
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
        No
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
    $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
    $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    id = $('#id_delete').val();
});
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: 'photos/' + id,
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
            $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
            $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                $(this).html(index+1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $delete = Photo::find($id);

    $delete->delete();

    return response()->json($delete);
}
```

Errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Abre developer tools (si usas chrome) y ve al apartado que te muestra las url que carga. Haz click en el icono/botón rojo y reintenta. Luego ahi mismo busca la dirección que cargó y revisa los detalles que te salieron y los anexas a tu pregunta.

Comment: Buenos días, ya los agregué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta incluyendo estos archivos:

```html
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
```